# strange interaction (bug ?) between mdframed and listings

Tags: listings, mdframed, debugging

I have a weird behaviour when I try to include some `lstlistings` inside a `mdframed` box. Most of the time, it works as expected, but under some conditions, I get incorrect output, or even a latex error (a `missing \item`, in this case)

I included a MWE below, with some stuff commented out for you to play with.

observations/questions:

- compilation goes fine if I remove the `mdframed` completely. But then my "paragraph 1" heading disappears. I can bring it back by adding e.g. an extra `~` afther the `\paragraph{}`. any clue why ?
- with `mdframed` included, compilation goes fine and the output looks correct if I remove the first `\paragraph{}` command. But with both, I get a `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` any clue why ?
- a workaround which seems to work for me is to enclose the `lstlisting` in a minipage. but how robust is this approach ?

**my main question is:** how do I troubleshoot this kind of problem, and/or who do I report it to ? is it a bug in `mdframed`, in `listings`, or in `article` ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}
  \paragraph{Paragraph 1}
  % \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
dummy verbatim text
\end{lstlisting}
  % \end{minipage}

  \paragraph{Paragraph 2} 
  \begin{itemize}
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \end{itemize}

\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to start a listing just after a sectional title is always a problem. In particular, if you try

```
\paragraph{Paragraph A}
\begin{lstlisting}
dummy verbatim text
\end{lstlisting}
```

at the top level (not inside `mdframed`), you'll notice that the heading disappears.

I don't think you want the listing to be next to the title: for instance,

```
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}
\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
\end{lstlisting}
```

would produce

[image]

which, most likely, is not what you want.

Solution: instead of `mdframed` use `tcolorbox` (I'll leave to you how to customize the enclosing box), that also cures several other glitches in `mdframed` and use `\mbox{}` after the sectional title, if a listing immediately follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Paragraph A}\mbox{}
\begin{lstlisting}
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
\end{lstlisting}

\paragraph{Paragraph B}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\end{itemize}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\paragraph{Paragraph 1}\mbox{}
\begin{lstlisting}
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
dummy verbatim text
\end{lstlisting}

\paragraph{Paragraph 2}
\begin{itemize}
\item first item
\item second item
\end{itemize}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for all the useful advice. Indeed, tcolorbox is the way to go (and its documentation is wonderful).

Answer (score 3):

I would use tcolorbox instead of mdframed -- much more robust. And you will have to add a \leavevmode to avoid that your \paragraph disappear:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  \paragraph{Paragraph 1}\leavevmode
\begin{lstlisting}
dummy verbatim text
\end{lstlisting}


  \paragraph{Paragraph 2}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item first item
  \item second item
  \end{itemize}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `verbatim`-like environment are notorious in causing a lot of headaches, and getting around them can be quite difficult.  Fortunately, the [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) provides an alternative to the default `verbatin`-like environments that works in more places.

In your particular case, you can set tell the `listings` package to use `fancyvrb` in order to collect the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  \paragraph{Listings} \leavevmode
  \begin{lstlisting}
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
      std::cout << "Hello World!";
    }
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: listings]

Another package to produce listings is [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) which also uses `fancyvrb` in order to collect the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  \paragraph{Minted}
  \begin{minted}[autogobble]{c++}
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
      std::cout << "Hello World!";
    }
  \end{minted}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: minted]